# PHP, Rest Service, Croatian letters as a value of parameters in POST request JSON body

Tags: php, json, rest, post, encoding

I have a problem with my PHP MVC. I'm trying to send some values of JSON parameters (in HTTP  POST request body) that include Croatian signs like ŠČĆŽĐŽ (from Android client). But on the PHP Controller side, when I echo JSON body of HTTP request, I'm getting ? (question marks) instead of those letters (I'm using `file_get_contents('php://input');`)

I tried absolutely everything I found on Internet, and it didn’t help. When I'm getting some values from MySQL database that include those letters, and echo it in PHP, everything is ok.

Here is the part of code. I commented some code that I tried before

```
//header('Content-Type: text/html; ISO-8859-1');
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   // get tag
   //$opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8'));
   //$context = stream_context_create($opts);
   inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
   echo utf8_encode($inputJSON);
   echo $inputJSON;
   //$fileEndEnd = mb_convert_encoding($inputJSON, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');                     //$fileEndEnd = htmlentities($inputJSON, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
   //$string = http_get_request_body ();
   //$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $inputJSON);
$fileEndEnd = mb_convert_encoding($inputJSON, 'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($inputJSON,      'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
   //echo $fileEndEnd;
   echo $fileEndEnd;
   //echo $string;
   //echo 'Badalićeva';
   $input= json_decode($inputJSON);

 //some code

 function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
   $content = file_get_contents($fn);
   return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8');
}
```